# Q:Fold and unfold cell content

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I have a requirement to fold and unfold my `tableview cell`, but I tried to realize the function I failed. In my method:
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
static NSString *cell_id = @"cell_id";    
    TableViewCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell_id];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell1" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;

    }
```

When I use delegate method to update my `tableView's cell` height:

```
- (void)changeFrame {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];

    //[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];

    [self.tableView reloadSections:set withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

But I found a issue, it will pass the `cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell1" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;`
code, I am sure in the `xib` of my cell, I have set the `Identity` and `Identifier` to `cell_id`.

So I can not set `numberOfLines` of my `cell's contentLabel`. Is there something wrong?

my requirement is this:
[image: my requrement]